# changing sub-sublist into tuples in python

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, tuples

I have a variable representing a bmp image with the following structure:

```
image=[line1, line2, ... linen] 
line=[pix1,pix2,...,pixn]
pix=[r,g,b]
```

thus for instance the contents of this variable may look like

```
[[[0,0,0],[1,0,1],[2,4,5]],[[3,4,5],[1,7,4],[1,3,5]],[[2,4,2],[1,6,7],[1,9,0]]]
```

Now I would like to convert the pix-lists of each line-item into tuples, so the contents will become like this:

```
[[(0,0,0),(1,0,1),(2,4,5)],[(3,4,5),(1,7,4),(1,3,5)],[(2,4,2),(1,6,7),(1,9,0)]]
```

I could do this by

```
for i in range(0,len(image)-1):
   for j in range(0,len(image[0])-1):
      image[i][j] = tuple(image[i][j])
```

but this doesn't seem to be the most "pythonesque" way to do it, and I need the fastest computational method possible, which the above seems to be far from.

I tried it with

```
[tuple(pix) for pix in line for line in image]
```

as I though this should be faster, but of course the above fails miserably.

So is there anybody who could help me convert my sublists of pix into tuples the fastest way possible? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this:

```
[map(tuple, line) for line in image]
```

And to encompass comments for completeness.  In Python 3.x, where map is a generator, you'd use:

```
[list(map(tuple, line)) for line in image]
```

Comment: I think that should be `map(tuple, line)`.

Comment: +1, you might also want to note that on Python 3.x, `map()` is a generator so you would want `list(map(...))`.

Comment: @F.J - I thought of that, but because it's specifically for 2.7 I figured it was ok.

Comment: Thanks guys, these replies came so fast!! This is a more elegant solution than I came up with. Sadly it is not necessarily faster for a bmp of 1024x768 (around 800ms on my 3ghz C2D quad), but I guess this just involves a really cpu intensive operation which cannot be executed quicker

Answer (score 4):

```
[[tuple(pix) for pix in line] for line in image]
```